# Serving React application with relative path

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I'm having two React applications running on the same machine. I'm using an nginx reverse proxy to handle routing requests.

The first application is running on root: '/', here is the nginx rule for it:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;   
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;  # for ssl
    }
```

The other app is running on port 4000, using the following reverse proxy:

```
location /staging/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;  # for ssl
    }
```

I followed the [documentation][1] for deployment and I added the following to my package.js:

```
"homepage": "https:/xyz.com/staging/"
```

The application works using npm start. However using:

```
npm run build && serve -s build -l 4000
```

fails to load.
The request to index.html is fine however, every time the app tries to request the *static* content, it always responds with the *index.html* contents:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I tried setting PUBLIC_URL as well, but also failed.
Why is react failing to respond with any thing in the static directory?
Any help appreciated.
[1]: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijqx9.png